# Job cannot be run because the SSIS subsystem failed to load. The job has been suspended

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting the following error when trying to run any of the Maintenance Task jobs that had been created on the server:

```
Message 
[LOG] Step 1 of job 'Weekly Backup' (0x8EC76A988468C74897562440AADD067D) cannot be run because the SSIS subsystem failed to load.  The job has been suspended
```

The Maintenance task was originally set up months ago and ran fine about until this week.  When checking the Sql Server Agent logs, I see the above error.  I have tried restarting services, reboot (in case of file locks?), and I've also tried the advice from here: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=914171

```
use msdb
go
delete from msdb.dbo.syssubsystems
exec msdb.dbo.sp_verify_subsystems 1
go
```

And restarting SQL Agent.

Same problem continues and the job is marked as Suspended. Any ideas?

Comment: You also need to restart SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

What changed on the server this week?  Any permissions issues, patches, uninstalls, etc?  Hotfixes / SP / Updates to SQL Server?

Here are a couple of thoughts:

- Look in the SQL Server log files and the Windows Application and System event logs for messages that might give you more detail on what the specific problem is.
- Make sure you see SQL Server Integration Services in your list of services and that it's running. (I'm assuming you're doing this when you're restarting services, though)
- Run this query on your server: `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.syssubsystems WHERE subsystem='SSIS'` and make sure that you get a record back in the result set.  If not, then you probably need to reinstall Integration Services on your server.
- If you do get a record back from the query in the previous point, verify that the files exist in the paths in the `subsystem_dll` and `agent_exe` columns and that the permisions on the folders and files are good.  If the files don't exist you'll probably need to reinstall Integration Services.

Comment: Thanks @squillman.  Unfortunately I couldn't get a 100% definite answer on the cause and most likely re-installing SSIS will work.  I suspect the timing of the issue around same time as a batch of windows updates / patches. +1 for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This can happen on a server with multiple instances and one of them has been upgraded.  SQL 2005 and 2008 SSIS subsytems are not very compatable with each other and when you do a SQL 2008 in place upgrade it will upgrade SSIS, changing the path to DTExec and the required dlls.

Comment: Thanks @jason.  See my answer to @squillman. +1 for the answer